# "MediaTomb UI is disabled. Check your configuration." What could I be forgetting?

Tags: installation, mediatomb

Upon initial installation of mediatomb I receive the following message:

> MediaTomb UI is disabled. Check your configuration.

What could I be missing on this configuration?

Comment: The installation finished correctly or it didn't finish? Can you run it without troubles?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it in a while, but documentation specified an IP address you need to enter in your web-browser. This takes you to a web-based configuration page where you can tell it where your media is.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out for myself.

My problem arised from when I transferred a config.xml file from an older computer to a newer one. Come to find out the service mediatomb reads the config.xml file located i the /etc/mediatomb directory, and when the config.xml file in ~/.mediatomb is replace it no longer has the same information in the /etc dir as the ~/ dir.

With a little deductive reasoning I concluded the config.xml located ~/.mediatomb must be a hard link to the /etc/mediatomb/config.xml file. So cd into /etc/mediatomb, sudo rm config.xml, then sudo ln ~/.mediatomb/config.xml should produce the correct results, then just restart the service. In list format:

cd /etc/mediatomb; sudo rm config.xml; sudo ln ~/.mediatomb/config.xml; sudo service mediatomb restart; exit

Otherwise if you have a new install check the ~/.mediatomb/config.xml file with nano and confirm ui enabled is in fact enabled. List format

nano ~/.mediatomb/config.xml 
ctrl+w "ui enabled" 
change no to yes 
ctrl+x 
y 
enter

Hopes this helps people looking for this answer, happy hacking

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install of MediaTomb on Peppermint 4, based on Ubuntu 13.04, and also got "MediaTomb UI is disabled. Check your configuration." I fixed this by editting ~/.mediatomb/config.xml and changing the line:

```
<accounts enabled="no" session-timeout="30">
```

to

```
<accounts enabled="yes" session-timeout="30">
```

I also inserted

```
<port>49152</port>
```

immediately after the line containig just `<server>` as I found a service restart command was too fast, and the port had not finished closing when the restart was issued. Mediatomb will use the next available port in this case - but it means you won't see the web page unless you chase the port number up!

I finished off by running the following:

```
sudo mv /etc/mediatomb/config.xml /etc/mediatomb/config.xml.bak
sudo cp ~/.mediatomb/config.xml /etc/mediatomb/config.xml
sudo service mediatomb restart
```

This stopped me getting "page note found" in the browser and, when it did display the login page, username mediatomb with password mediatomb would not work.

Hope this helps someone as I spent a lot of time on it.